# (Java) Is there a type of object that can handle anything from primitives to arrays?

Tags: java, polymorphism

I'm pretty new to Java, so I'm hoping one of you guys knows how to do this.  I'm having the user specify both the type and value of arguments, in any XML-like way, to be passed to methods that are external to my application.

Example: javac myAppsName externalJavaClass methodofExternalClass [parameters]

Of course, to find the proper method, we have to have the proper parameter types as the method may be overloaded and that's the only way to tell the difference between the different versions.  Parameters are currently formatted in this manner:

(type)value(/type), e.g. (int)71(/int) (string)This is my string that I'm passing as a parameter!(/string)

I parse them, getting the constructor for whatever type is indicated, then execute that constructor by running its method, `newInstance(<String value>)`, loading the new instance into an `Object`.  This works fine and dandy, but as we all know, some methods take arrays, or even multi-dimensional arrays.

I could handle the argument formatting like so: `(array)(array)(int)0(/int)(int)1(/int)(/array)(array)(int)2(/int)(int)3(/int)(/array)(/array)`... or perhaps even better... `{{(int)0(/int)(int)1(/int)}{(int)2(/int)(int)3(/int)}}`.

The question is, how can this be implemented?  Do I have to start wrapping everything in an Object[] array so I can handle primitives, etc. as argObj[0], but load an array as I normally would?  (Unfortunately, I would have to make it an Object[][] array if I wanted to support two-dimensional arrays.  This implementation wouldn't be very pretty.)

Comment: I also think **JSON** is suitable for this situation. there's a JSON library called **[json-lib](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/usage.html)**, [net.sf.json.JSONArray javadoc](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/jdk15/net/sf/json/JSONArray.html#fromObject(java.lang.Object)). example: `System.out.println (net.sf.json.JSONArray.fromObject("[1,'string', ['two-dimension', 'array', 2.2]]"));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for here is a way to dynamically call Java methods based on attributes described inside an XML file.

If that's the case, you can explore the Java Reflection API.

Example class:

```
package foo;
public class Bar {

    public void doSomething(String x) {
        System.out.println("This is a method doSomething that takes in a String parameter");
    }

    public void doSomething(String [] arr, String str) {
        System.out.println("This is a method doSomething that takes in a String arr parameter and a String parameter");
    }
}
```

To dynamically use the methods in this class, do the following:

```
Class c = Class.forName("foo.Bar");
Object newInstance = c.newInstance();
Method method = c.getMethod("doSomething", String.class);
// This will locate the first method
method.invoke(newInstance, "Hello World");

Method method = c.getMethod("doSomething", String[].class, String.class);
// This will locate the second method

String [] arr = {"Hello", "World"};
method.invoke(newInstance, arr, "Hello World");
```

So you can specify in your XML file as follows:

```
<method>
    <name>doSomething</name>
    <params>
        <param>java.lang.String</param>
    </params>
</method>
<method>
    <name>doSomething</name>
    <params>
        <param>java.lang.String[]</param>   // or any other annotation to indicate that its an arr
        <param>java.lang.String</param>
    </params>
</method>
```

Then, read the XML file and use it to find the Java methods dynamically.

To dynamically create an array:

```
Class c = Class.forName("java.lang.String");
int length = 5;
Object o = Array.newInstance(c, length); // o is a String arr of length 5
String [] arr = (String []) o;
```

Comment: Right, but you have used known functions with known parameter types (String.class and String[].class, String.class).  Here is my code: `Method theMethod = theClass.getMethod(args[1], argsClassArray); ret = theMethod.invoke(null, argsObjectArray);`  I have to fill argsClassArray with classes plucked from user input, and those classes may be anything -- int, String, String[], int[][].

Comment: In response to your new edit, yes, something like that, but the issue is how can I change the parsed text "String[].class" into an actual Class variable?  Can I do `Class.forName("String[]");`?  I hadn't thought about that.

Comment: if you are talking about arrays though, you should be looking at java reflections array API

Comment: String [] arr = (String [] )Array.newInstance(String.class, length);

Comment: Couldn't get `Class thisClass = Class.forName("String[]");` to work, but the reflective call of Array's constructor works to produce an array of a dynamic type, so this should do trick just fine.  Thanks!

Comment: You have to say `Class.forName("[String;")`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is, and it's called `java.lang.Object`. You can even assign arrays like `int[][]` to an variable declared as `java.lang.Object`.

But I fear that's not what you wanted. It seems that you are writing a client-service framework -- the client (your user) pass some data to the service (your app). There're existing libraries that can do the same thing, e.g., Thrift, Protobuf. If you are looking for XML-based solution, there is SOAP.

Comment: In regards to what I am doing, I am making my second Java application ever, the first being "Hello, world!"

Comment: I tried loading an int array into an Object and it produced an error: invoke.java:28: error: `array required, but Object found, dummy[0] = "Blimey!";` from the code: `Object dummy; dummy = new String[10]; dummy[0] = "Blimey!";`  (Sorry... had to delete the previous version.  Was too late to edit it.  Haha.)

Comment: @Michael if this is your second java app, my advice is to slow down! Make something that only passes the same simple type back and forwards, then build up to different types

Comment: Technically you can put anything into an `Object` variable -- `dummy` if you like, but it's a different thing when you tries to use it. You need to "convert" `dummy` to an actual string array before you access its cells: `((String[])dummy)[0] = "Blimey!";` And things are going to get messy when `dummy` may hold different types of value (string, integer, double, arrays, ...) NOT a good approach I'd say.

Comment: @infgeoax So what would be a good approach, then?  I spent quite a bit of time writing this application, and the inability to handle arrays is the only thing standing in the way of it being complete. ^_^  I think I could manage to do it the way that you describe.  I could push and pop Arrays from a stack, using them to form arrays of the base type, like so: `/* Class baseClass = String.class; */  for (int i=0; i<StackCount; i++) { ((baseClass[])arrayClass) = Array.newInstance(baseclass, 0);  baseClass = arrayClass.class; }`  That should work, right?

Comment: @dann.dev The Java book I'm reading is rather fast-paced.  Outside of some methods of the String class, I don't think I've used anything in this application that hasn't been covered in the book, and I'm only 25% of the way through it.  Who knows what goodies are in store for me in the next chapter!  :p

Answer (score 3):

What you're really looking for is JSON, and one of the Java kits for handling it.